# Xamarin Forms: How to access button name in XAML from C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML markup:

```
<ListView x:Name="wordsListView">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
               <StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Keyword}" />
                  <Button Text="Click Me" x:Name="randomButton"></Button>
               </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And in my .xaml.cs file I have the button clicked event for the `random` button defined as below:

```
randomButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    a = rand.Next(words.Count);
    word = words[a];
};
```

But somehow when I build my project I kept getting an error: `The name randomButton does not exists in the current context.` Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how it should be done?

Comment: You can't access an element that is defined inside a template.  Instead assign the Click handler (or use a Command) in the XAML.

Comment: Have a look into using Interactivity and Behaviors within XAML. You can then use a `Command` in your DataContext (view model or code-behind) that takes the `type` of item that are being displayed in the `ListView`. You would need to set `IsItemClickEnabled="True"` in the `ListView` declaration. Here's a handy reference on using behaviors: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/ *edit: I would seriously consider looking into using MVVM practice :)*

Answer (score 2):

You can't access any control by name or even give it a name as long as it is on template view , naming it is not appropriate as long as this control on template will be repeated on run time!

but you can access the whole control from the Sender of the click event ... and this depends on your development approach

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help others.

There is nothing wrong with your code.You can try these 2 ways:

First, save xaml file and use this.randomButton. Try if it works.

Else Clean the solution and try again. If that didn't work, restart the Visual Studio.